# How to use `useSelector` in a class based component? React, Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I wanna get the data from my Redux storage, not an error :)

**In a function based component I always do like this**

```reactjs
...

import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export deafult function App(...){
  ...

  const someData = useSelector(state => state.someData);

  ...
  return (...)
}
...
```

**But when it comes to a class based component I want smth like this, but I get an error :(**

```reactjs
...
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export default class App  extends Component {
  constructor(...){
    ...
    
    const someData = useSelector(state => state.someData);

    ...
  }

  render(...)
}
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hooks only works with functional components

Instead of useSelector you can pass you props from react-redux like this

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class App extends React.Component{
...

//Your data from react-redux can be called like this.props.someData
const someData = this.props.someData;

...
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
     return {
         someData: state.someData
     }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

Comment: So the const is to be defined in the render method? Also the attribute i set in the redux store is undefined. Your comment isnt too clear